# Erlang Binary Tree function

Tags: tree, erlang, binary-tree

I have a Perfect Binary Tree which every node is represented like that

```
[Value, LeftNode, RightNode]
```

Value is the node value and 
each LeftNode and RightNode are the Node's sons which are too Binary Trees recursively. 
And the last nodes (leafs) are represented like that

```
[Value, [], []]
```

example:

```
L1=[4, [], []], 
L2=[5, [], []], 
L3=[6, [], []], 
L4=[7, [], []], 
L5=[2, L1, L2], 
L6=[3, L3, L4], 
Tree=[1,L5 , L6].
```

so I have the function that returns the last left leaf

```
lastLeftLeaf([H, [], []]) ->H;
lastLeftLeaf([H, Left, Right]) ->lastLeftLeaf(Left).
```

in our example it returns 4 :the value of L1. 
And the function that returns the tree without last left leaf:it replaces this leaf with []

```
withoutLastLeftLeaf([H, [], []]) ->[] ;
withoutLastLeftLeaf([H, Left, Right]) ->[H, withoutLastLeftLeaf(Left), Right].
```

in our example it returns the tree without L1: which replaced with []

both the functions do the same browse and to get results i must do two browses and for more performance and efficiency i want to create a function with just one browse that returns two results : the last left leaf and the tree without that leaf any help and thank you all.

Comment: “I want to create a function”—just do it.

Comment: ok show me how i can't realise it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two functions you have written, and have the new function return a result of the form `{Value, NewTree}`.  For the case where you're already at the leaf, it's simple:

```
take_last_left_leaf([H, [], []]) -> {H, []};
```

Then, at any other point in the tree, you would recurse into the left branch, get the value and the new left branch, and then return the value along with the modified tree:

```
take_last_left_leaf([H, Left, Right]) ->
    {Value, NewLeft} = take_last_left_leaf(Left),
    {Value, [H, NewLeft, Right]}.
```

Comment: Thank you legoscia this is very genius and you helped me a lot so thank you, the difficulty in Erlang language is that there is no generale rule to use unlike all other languages that I used, in this example I noted that you have build recursivity from the last and this is new idea for me.

Comment: I try to solve complexe advanced algorithms like all types of list sort and dynamic programming so i think that's a good practise for erlang language thank you legoscia

Comment: Indeed! The principle I'm using here is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction - first write a function clause to handle the simplest case (a leaf node), and then write a function clause that applies the solution for a larger case.

Comment: ues I know this is the recursion principe and i'm used it for a long time but with erlang its a bit stranger for me and i found some difficulty to realise recursive algorithms because of the limited syntax of the language so for example this Tree function will be very easy in Java, I do just the withoutLastLeftLeaf function then in the last case at the level of leafs I use a global variable that is bounded after the end of the function

Comment: legoscia do you have any site or pdf for hard erlang algorithms exercises ?

Comment: iam new hear and i did not know how to accept answers, so i did my job thank you brother.